# Write out the first few terms of the Picard iteration scheme for $x' = x^{4/3}; x(0) = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Write out the first few terms of the Picard iteration scheme for $x' = x^{4/3}; x(0) = 0 $. Find explicit solution and describe the domain of this solution.

$x' = x^{4/3}; x(0) = 0 $

The first few terms of the Picard iteration I found is all zero.

Is the explicit solution just zero or I am missing something?

Comment: $x(t) \equiv 0$ is an obvious solution, isn't it? What can you say about uniqueness? Consider the closed intervall $[-a,a]$ for arbitary $a$, is $g(t,x) = x^{4/3}$ lipschitz in $x$?

Comment: @user127.0.0.1: is "lipschitz" meaning continuous? If so, since x(t) = 0, how can we relate t to x in this case since x' does not depend on t?

Comment: *Lipschitz (continuity)* is stronger than regular continuity. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity

Comment: The Picard-Lindelöf-Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) now tells you that you have a **unique** solution on every closed intervall (in particular including the 0), hence $x\equiv0$ is the only solution for your DE

Comment: under what condition, does this Thm tell me I have a unique solution on every interval?

Comment: that question is answered in the link above!

Comment: when X = 0??????

Answer (score 1):

The exact solution, if you hadn't worked it out explicitely, is

> $x(t) = -\frac{27}{(C+t)^3}$.

With the information that $x(0) = 0$, we can see that $0 = -\frac{27}{(C+0)^3} = -\frac{27}{C^3}$ which is only valid at

> $C = \infty$.

With $C = 0$,

> $x(t) = -\frac{27}{(\infty)^3} = 0$

So your answer makes sense. Hope that helps. You probably already knew that though.